# I have to do this task (online shop) using "switch" statements. I got stuck

Tags: java, switch-statement

"Write a Java program to simulate an online store. The program should begin
by displaying a list of products and their prices. There should be a minimum of 4
products offered.

My code is below, it works without the strings but I need to have names for the cakes(display names and prices)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in)

    
    int cakeNo = 0;
    double cake1;
    double cake2;
    double cake3;
    double cake4;
    double cake5;
    int quantity;
    
    double totalSales = 0;
    
    while(cakeNo !=0 )
     
     System.out.println("Enter cake number 1-5");
     cakeNo=input.nextInt();
     
     System.out.println("Enter quantity");
     quantity = input.nextInt();
     
     switch (cakeNo){
         
         case 1: cake1 = 3.70;
     totalSales+=(3.70*quantity);
     break;
         case 2: cake2 = 4.20;
     totalSales+=(4.20*quantity);
     break;
         case 3: cake3 = 4.50;
     totalSales+=(4.50*quantity);
     break;
         case 4: cake4 = 5.00;
     totalSales+=(5.00*quantity);
     break;
         case 5: cake5 = 5.50;
     totalSales+=(5.50*quantity);
     break;
     
     }
     
     System.out.println(totalSales);  
}  
    
}
```

Thank you so much for reading! Please help if you have an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are a few things wrong in your code that you should take care first.

**First**: The first 5 string are wrongly defined. It should be like this `String cake1 = "Angel cake"` and so on.

**Second**: The strings and doubles have the same names you cannot do that. You need to have something like `String cake1Name = "Name"` and `double cake1Price = price` this way you have two distinct properties for everycake.

**Third**: Right now the code doesn't even enters the while loop. Since cakeNo starts with 0 and the condition in your while loop is `cakeNo != 0` right on before the first loop this condition will be tested and it will be false meaning that the loop code won't be executed and will jump to the end of the program.

After this fixes there is still a little problem. After you get the input from the user if said input is 0 meaning that he wants to leave the program will still ask him for a quantity. You need to add/change something that breaks the loop when this conditions is true. I don't want to give you code but I hope this answer can help you good luck :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew I have things missing but couldn't find a solution. I'm new in programming. Will do this and see how it works. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

```
public class Main {

LinkedList<Product> cart = new LinkedList<Product> ();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
double tax = 7.5;
boolean done = false;

public Main() {
        cart.add(new Product("Cake 1", 3.70));
        cart.add(new Product("Cake 2", 4.20));
        cart.add(new Product("Cake 3", 4.50));
        cart.add(new Product("Cake 4", 5.00));
        cart.add(new Product("Cake 5", 5.50));
    }

    public void displayCart() {
        for (int i = 0; i < cart.size(); i++) {
            switch (cart.get(i).quantitySelected){
            case 0:
                System.out.println(i + ": " + cart.get(i).name + "   none selected");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println(i + ": " + cart.get(i).name + "   selected: " + cart.get(i).quantitySelected);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void addToCart(int product, int amount) {
        cart.get(product).select(amount);
    }

    public void getSelection() {

        int productSelected;

        System.out.println("enter a product value or FINNISHED to end: ");

        try {
            productSelected = scanner.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            done = true;

            return;
        }

        System.out.println("enter amount to select: ");

        int amount = scanner.nextInt();

        cart.get(productSelected).select(amount);
    }

    public double getSubtotal() {

        double cost = 0.00;

        for (Product product : cart) {
            cost += product.cost * product.quantitySelected;
        }

        return cost;
    }

    public double getTotal() {
        return getSubtotal() + getSubtotal()*tax;
    }

    public void finnishPurchase() {
        System.out.println("---------------------");
        System.out.println("subtotal: " + getSubtotal());
        System.out.println("tax: " + tax);
        System.out.println("total: " + getTotal());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main store = new Main();

        while (!store.done) {
            store.displayCart();
            store.getSelection();
        }

        store.finnishPurchase();
    }
}
public class Product {
    String name;
    double cost;

    int quantitySelected = 0;

    public Product(String name, double cost) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public void select(int quantity) {
        quantitySelected = quantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is the requirement, to use switch statement. Will try this and see how it works. Thank you so much!